# Nginx: proxy_intercept_errors - get response body

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a requirement where when proxied response error code is 401 (*condition #1*) and response body has text "No SAML Token" (*condition #2*), I need to intercept it and redirect to refresh token API.

I could do it partially where only error code 401 is considered. Not able to find a way to read response body text to give *condition #2*:

```
location /service {
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   error_page 401 = @refresh;
}
location @refresh {

   (# Here check if the response body has text "No SAML Token". If yes return 401 directly.)

   set $original_uri $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
   return 307 https://localhost:8083/service/auth/refresh?uri=$original_uri;
}
```

Please help me on getting the response body text. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from Nginx forum.

*"There is no way. Errors are intercepted based on the response
headers, and the response body is not read from the upstream
server if the error is intercepted.
If you need to analyze the response body, consider using njs
instead. Doing appropriate subrequest and looking into it might
work for you, see here for details:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html
[http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/reference.html#subrequest"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/reference.html#subrequest%22)*

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,288683,288689#msg-288689